# How do I split or grab a string in python after a comma in python

Tags: python

How would you split a string for every comma it pass it 
For example, let say I want to grab only the BigCity  etc

s="1234 Somestreet Road, BigCity, SomeProvince, A1B 1C1"

so, 
city = s.split? 
How would i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
x=s.split(',')

if len(x)>1:
    x=x[1:] # since you are only concerned with what comes after a ','
    print x[0].strip() # remove the strip(), depends on the usage
else:
    print ''
```

s="1234 Somestreet Road"  => empty string

s="1234 Somestreet Road," => empty string

s="1234 Somestreet Road, BigCity, SomeProvince, A1B 1C1" => BigCity

Comment: So how would you store the string for SomeProvince

Comment: if there are more than 1 items after the split, they are all there in the list variable "x" after doing "x=x[1:]". Depending on the usage, modify the line "print x[0].strip()"

Answer (score -1):

```
In [247]: s="1234 Somestreet Road, BigCity, SomeProvince, A1B 1C1"

In [248]: s.split(',')
Out[248]: ['1234 Somestreet Road', ' BigCity', ' SomeProvince', ' A1B 1C1']

In [249]: s.split(',')[1]
Out[249]: ' BigCity'
```

Comment: What about: `s.split(', ', 2)[1]` ? (still runs the same risk of `IndexError`s though)

Comment: @JonClements: indeed... but the question is super underspecified